# What are Global handles and GC roots in Node js heap inspector?

Tags: node.js, memory-management, garbage-collection, v8, node-inspector

I am trying to inspect the heap of a running express node js app.

In the heap dump comparison it looks like some strings are not being freed.
The promises they are tied to are resolved but the Retainers chain goes up to Global handles and then to GC roots. I am not following what these mean.

Can someone shed light on this?
Why is the GC unable to collect these resolved promises?

[image: node js heap snapshot]

Answer (score 1):

Node holds a reference to every promise created when async_hooks is enabled, and to promises that have rejected in order to display unhandled rejection warnings.

PromiseWrap is what async_hooks uses, and that random array is an array that unhandled rejection tracking uses.

Note that unhandled rejection tracking can't be disabled :(, but you can rest assured they are responsibly cleaned up.

Comment: Okay, but when I run the GC, the memory is not being freed up. I'm using the --inspect flag on node.js and chrome to generate these heaps

Comment: @Ali right, because node is still holding them internally.

Comment: @snek but does that mean it's a form of memory leak, or it just being held onto for the sake of profiling; ie using the --trace flag causes Node to hold onto them?